# MySQL SELECT with data from another table

Tags: mysql

Probably it's easier than what i think, but i am loosing my mind about it,
i have a table with product with thousand of entry, something like

```
ID|NAME
0 |first product
1 |second product
...
N |nth product
```

every time someone click a product i save and update a table called click

```
PRODUCT_ID|CLICKS
0         |1
1         |3
```

so, if a product never received a click does not exist in click table

now i want a list of all the products (or a category subset for example) ordered by clicks.
of course the entry that are not on click table should be present in the result with clicks column to 0 (or empty)

```
ID|NAME       |CLICKS
0 |first name |1
5 |fifth name |
...
N |nth name   |2
```

all the joins i tried were only able to give me a combined result for entry that are present in both table, i know its very easy and i am running around it from about two hours... but i cant succeed!
any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a query you're currently using? `LEFT JOIN` (https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx/) is likely what you're looking for. This will join the tables with `NULL` values for `CLICKS` if they don't exist.

Comment: thank you! was almost there, missing the LEFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select from master table and make it LEFT JOIN with clicks table.

Answer (score 1):

a [LEFT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) works for your query

> ```
> CREATE TABLE products (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `NAME` VARCHAR(14)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO products
>   (`ID`, `NAME`)
> VALUES
>   ('0', 'first product'),
>   ('1', 'second product'),
>   ('2', 'thirdproduct'),
>   ('3', 'forth product');
> ```

> 

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ciicks (
>   `PRODUCT_ID` INTEGER,
>   `CLICKS` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO ciicks
>   (`PRODUCT_ID`, `CLICKS`)
> VALUES
>   ('0', '1'),
>   ('1', '3');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT p.ID,p.NAME,IFNULL(c.CLICKS,0)
> FROM products p LEFT JOIN ciicks c ON p.ID = c.PRODUCT_ID
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | NAME           | IFNULL(c.CLICKS,0)
> -: | :------------- | -----------------:
>  0 | first product  |                  1
>  1 | second product |                  3
>  2 | thirdproduct   |                  0
>  3 | forth product  |                  0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=217b3c06bedd8ef9b28e2e63757ec77f)*

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.id, p.name, ifnull(c.clicks,0) as clicks from product p
left join click c on p.id = c.product_id
```

Comment: Also, it's recommended to explain how your code addresses/solves the OP's question. Code only answers are frowned upon. Adding info allows visitors to quickly zoom in on the important bits, is quicker to cognitively digest, and helps fire visitors learn, and apply knowledge to their own code. This then favors Q &A for knowledge, over "give me the code" as a service Q and A. It also keeps quality high for SO as a platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` (https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx/) to combine tables where one table may not have matching rows. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db9d5a/4 for an example:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    IFNULL(c.clicks, 0)
FROM
    products p
    LEFT JOIN clicks c ON c.product_id = p.id
ORDER BY c.clicks DESC;
```

will return the following:

```
id | name   | clicks
4    fourth   5
2    second   3
1    first    1
3    third    0
```